# Debian + Bumblebee doesn't run CUDA

Tags: debian, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda, optimus

I have laptop with descrete NVIDIA card and Debian Wheezy. I need use NVIDIA Optimus and CUDA.

When I install Bumbleebee NVIDIA Optimus work correctly, but I can't run CUDA programs. This falls on `getDevice()`.

How I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131506/how-can-i-get-nvidia-cuda-or-opencl-working-on-a-laptop-with-nvidia-discrete-car) from askubuntu, but since I'm new to Debian and have used ubuntu for a long time, I don't really like that all the guides are for ubuntu and I'm a bit lost, and was disappointed that no one has answered you here.
Good luck

P.S: I couldn't comment because I don't have 50 reputations yet.